# Currency in Google Spreadsheet format

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet with an amount column in different currencies. The currency is defined in Financial format in the cell. How can I get the currency of the cell from the script?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow please look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please provide us with information on what you have tried.

Comment: I have in sheet column values like this:
140.80
2.90
4026.78
35.50
30.10
They are formatted with menu "Format=>Number=>Currency=>Currency Sign" and are displayed like this:
kn140.80
€2.90
din4,027
€35.50
€30.10
Script loops through the column and processes each value according to it's currency. So for each cell in addition to value I need a format element which defines its currency. How can I get it?

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
 =regexreplace(substitute(substitute(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",),",",)," ",),"\d+",)
```